# 'list' object has no attribute 'text

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

That's the tbody i want scraping with beautiful Soup

in one of online browser stock game .

```html
<tbody>
  <tr class="stock visible-xs">
    <td colspan="3"> <a href="#viewStock" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" data-id="12"> Band Alizarin </a> </td>
    <td> <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-up"></i> $7,300 </td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="stock">
    <td> <input type="text" class="table-input" name="stock[ 12 ]" value="0" data-max-buy="1659"> </td>
    <td class="text-center"> <input readonly="" type="text" class="table-input" value="0"> </td>
    <td class="text-left hidden-xs"> <a href="#viewStock" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" data-id="12"> Band Alizarin </a> </td>
    <td class="text-left hidden-xs"> <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-up"></i> $7,300 </td>
    <td class="text-left"> <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus"></i> 0% </td>
    <td class="text-left"> $0 </td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="stock visible-xs">
    <td colspan="3"> <a href="#viewStock" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" data-id="15"> Bottled Inc. </a> </td>
    <td> <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down"></i> $7,939 </td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="stock">
    <td> <input type="text" class="table-input" name="stock[ 15 ]" value="0" data-max-buy="1525"> </td>
    <td class="text-center"> <input readonly="" type="text" class="table-input" value="0"> </td>
    <td class="text-left hidden-xs"> <a href="#viewStock" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" data-id="15"> Bottled Inc. </a> </td>
    <td class="text-left hidden-xs"> <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down"></i> $7,939 </td>
    <td class="text-left"> <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus"></i> 0% </td>
    <td class="text-left"> $0 </td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="stock visible-xs">
    <td colspan="3"> <a href="#viewStock" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" data-id="9"> Crime Online ISP </a> </td>
    <td> <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-up"></i> $4,440 </td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="stock">
    <td> <input type="text" class="table-input" name="stock[ 9 ]" value="0" data-max-buy="2727"> </td>
    <td class="text-center"> <input readonly="" type="text" class="table-input" value="0"> </td>
    <td class="text-left hidden-xs"> <a href="#viewStock" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" data-id="9"> Crime Online ISP </a> </td>
    <td class="text-left hidden-xs"> <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-up"></i> $4,440 </td>
    <td class="text-left"> <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus"></i> 0% </td>
    <td class="text-left"> $0 </td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="stock visible-xs">
    <td colspan="3"> <a href="#viewStock" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" data-id="4"> Dark Minds Holding </a> </td>
    <td> <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down"></i> $542 </td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="stock">
    <td> <input type="text" class="table-input" name="stock[ 4 ]" value="0" data-max-buy="4040"> </td>
    <td class="text-center"> <input readonly="" type="text" class="table-input" value="0"> </td>
    <td class="text-left hidden-xs"> <a href="#viewStock" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" data-id="4"> Dark Minds Holding </a> </td>
    <td class="text-left hidden-xs"> <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down"></i> $542 </td>
    <td class="text-left"> <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus"></i> 0% </td>
    <td class="text-left"> $0 </td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="stock visible-xs">
    <td colspan="3"> <a href="#viewStock" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" data-id="10"> DI Mobile </a> </td>
    <td> <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-up"></i> $5,670 </td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="stock">
    <td> <input type="text" class="table-input" name="stock[ 10 ]" value="0" data-max-buy="2136"> </td>
    <td class="text-center"> <input readonly="" type="text" class="table-input" value="0"> </td>
    <td class="text-left hidden-xs"> <a href="#viewStock" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" data-id="10"> DI Mobile </a> </td>
    <td class="text-left hidden-xs"> <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-up"></i> $5,670 </td>
    <td class="text-left"> <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus"></i> 0% </td>
    <td class="text-left"> $0 </td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="stock visible-xs">
    <td colspan="3"> <a href="#viewStock" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" data-id="7"> DM Server Hosting </a> </td>
    <td> <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down"></i> $1,695 </td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="stock">
    <td> <input type="text" class="table-input" name="stock[ 7 ]" value="0" data-max-buy="4040"> </td>
    <td class="text-center"> <input readonly="" type="text" class="table-input" value="0"> </td>
    <td class="text-left hidden-xs"> <a href="#viewStock" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" data-id="7"> DM Server Hosting </a> </td>
    <td class="text-left hidden-xs"> <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down"></i> $1,695 </td>
    <td class="text-left"> <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus"></i> 0% </td>
    <td class="text-left"> $0 </td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="stock visible-xs">
    <td colspan="3"> <a href="#viewStock" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" data-id="16"> FC Dark-Football </a> </td>
    <td> <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down"></i> $13,174 </td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="stock">
    <td> <input type="text" class="table-input" name="stock[ 16 ]" value="0" data-max-buy="0"> </td>
    <td class="text-center"> <input readonly="" type="text" class="table-input" value="4040"> </td>
    <td class="text-left hidden-xs"> <a href="#viewStock" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" data-id="16"> FC Dark-Football </a> </td>
    <td class="text-left hidden-xs"> <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down"></i> $13,174 </td>
    <td class="text-left"> <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-up"></i> 8.81% </td>
    <td class="text-left"> $53,222,960 </td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="stock visible-xs">
    <td colspan="3"> <a href="#viewStock" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" data-id="14"> Fly to the sky airlines </a> </td>
    <td> <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down"></i> $7,171 </td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="stock">
    <td> <input type="text" class="table-input" name="stock[ 14 ]" value="0" data-max-buy="1689"> </td>
    <td class="text-center"> <input readonly="" type="text" class="table-input" value="0"> </td>
    <td class="text-left hidden-xs"> <a href="#viewStock" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" data-id="14"> Fly to the sky airlines </a> </td>
    <td class="text-left hidden-xs"> <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down"></i> $7,171 </td>
    <td class="text-left"> <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus"></i> 0% </td>
    <td class="text-left"> $0 </td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="stock visible-xs">
    <td colspan="3"> <a href="#viewStock" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" data-id="11"> Leetcom </a> </td>
    <td> <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-up"></i> $6,781 </td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="stock">
    <td> <input type="text" class="table-input" name="stock[ 11 ]" value="0" data-max-buy="0"> </td>
    <td class="text-center"> <input readonly="" type="text" class="table-input" value="4040"> </td>
    <td class="text-left hidden-xs"> <a href="#viewStock" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" data-id="11"> Leetcom </a> </td>
    <td class="text-left hidden-xs"> <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-up"></i> $6,781 </td>
    <td class="text-left"> <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-up"></i> 27.49% </td>
    <td class="text-left"> $27,395,240 </td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="stock visible-xs">
    <td colspan="3"> <a href="#viewStock" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" data-id="5"> Mykrotech </a> </td>
    <td> <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-up"></i> $201 </td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="stock">
    <td> <input type="text" class="table-input" name="stock[ 5 ]" value="0" data-max-buy="0"> </td>
    <td class="text-center"> <input readonly="" type="text" class="table-input" value="4040"> </td>
    <td class="text-left hidden-xs"> <a href="#viewStock" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" data-id="5"> Mykrotech </a> </td>
    <td class="text-left hidden-xs"> <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-up"></i> $201 </td>
    <td class="text-left"> <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down"></i> 0% </td>
    <td class="text-left"> $812,040 </td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="stock visible-xs">
    <td colspan="3"> <a href="#viewStock" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" data-id="8"> Searchable </a> </td>
    <td> <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-up"></i> $3,402 </td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="stock">
    <td> <input type="text" class="table-input" name="stock[ 8 ]" value="0" data-max-buy="3560"> </td>
    <td class="text-center"> <input readonly="" type="text" class="table-input" value="0"> </td>
    <td class="text-left hidden-xs"> <a href="#viewStock" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" data-id="8"> Searchable </a> </td>
    <td class="text-left hidden-xs"> <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-up"></i> $3,402 </td>
    <td class="text-left"> <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus"></i> 0% </td>
    <td class="text-left"> $0 </td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="stock visible-xs">
    <td colspan="3"> <a href="#viewStock" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" data-id="13"> United Farmers </a> </td>
    <td> <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down"></i> $7,007 </td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="stock">
    <td> <input type="text" class="table-input" name="stock[ 13 ]" value="0" data-max-buy="1728"> </td>
    <td class="text-center"> <input readonly="" type="text" class="table-input" value="0"> </td>
    <td class="text-left hidden-xs"> <a href="#viewStock" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" data-id="13"> United Farmers </a> </td>
    <td class="text-left hidden-xs"> <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down"></i> $7,007 </td>
    <td class="text-left"> <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus"></i> 0% </td>
    <td class="text-left"> $0 </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td> <button name="type" value="buy" class="btn btn-link btn-block text-center" style="margin-bottom: 5px !important;"> Buy </button> <button name="type" value="sell" class="btn btn-link btn-block text-center"> Sell </button> </td>
    <td> </td>
    <td colspan="4"></td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

and i use this Code

```
driver.find_element_by_link_text('Stock Market').click()
source=driver.page_source
soup=BeautifulSoup(source,'lxml')
StockTable=soup.find('table',class_='table table-condensed table-responsive table-bordered table-striped')
# print(StockTable.prettify()) #<=====  It print perfect code 
tbody=StockTable.find('tbody')
# print(tbody.prettify())      #<=====  It print perfect code 
for tr in tbody.find_all('tr',class_='stock'):
    Data1=tr.find_all('td')[2:4].text
    print(Data1)
print(Data1)
```

and i always got that error
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "d:/sm/py-projects/ShootBot Project/alpha_stock.py", line 60, in 
Data1=tr.find_all('td')[2:4].text
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'text'

I only try to get Stock Name And Price Text. Please, Ineed to know what I miss in this code.

Comment: Because you say find all. You have to loop over the findings before you can textify them :)

Comment: `tr.find_all('td')` returns a list.  You need to access the `.text` attribute of the items _inside_ the list, not the list itself.

Comment: So with that <td class="text-center"> <input readonly="" type="text" class="table-input" value="0"> </td>         how i can Get that value in a list also  i want make a list with all that class="table-input" value="0"  >>> thanks for helping

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't work because you say find_all()... You have to loop over the findings before you can textify them :)

```
Data1=tr.find_all('td')[2:4]
for i in Data1:
    print(i.text)
```

Comment: This would be a better answer if you explained how the code you provided answers the question.

Comment: Yes sorry I just wrote it as a comment in his post. I will edit it now :)

Comment: So with that <td class="text-center"> <input readonly="" type="text" class="table-input" value="0"> </td> how i can Get that value in a list also i want make a list with all that class="table-input" value="0" >>> thanks for helping

Answer (score 0):

You can try iterate over the td's and print their text attribute

```
for tr in tbody.find_all('tr',class_='stock'):
    for td in tr.find_all('td')[2:4]:
        print(td.text)
```

Comment: You welcome, happy to assist. It will be appreciated if you will vote up and mark the answer.

Comment: So with that <td class="text-center"> <input readonly="" type="text" class="table-input" value="0"> </td> how i can Get that value in a list also i want make a list with all that class="table-input" value="0" >>> thanks for helping